# How can I show that Jesus (pbuh) is not a god to Christian friend using Quran as guidance?

Tags: quran, prophet-isa, christianity, shirk, dawah

I am a Muslim, and I have a Christian friend. He usually argue that Jesus (pbuh) is the God and the son of God. I know that Jesus is the son of Maryam and the messenger of Allah.

Please guide me with all the relevant ayath from Qur'an to show that Jesus is a messenger of Allah. I have promised him that I will show some proof in next meeting.

Comment: This is very much related, especially in light of AJ's answer: [A Christian view of Mohammad](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/33065) There are very few conversions between the two faiths.

Comment: You must realize that a Christian will not accept the authenticity of the Quran. You would have to show him using sources that he accepts as authentic.

Comment: I provide the answer through biblical guidance. I hope this minor alteration is acceptable.

Comment: Why he doesn't call Adam and Eva as son and daughter of god?!

Answer (score 18):

As a Christian, he isn't going to accept any evidence you provide from the Koran.  You would instead need to make an argument from the religious texts that he believes are valid.

To a Christian, the Koran is nothing more than a bunch of made up stories at best. It has no authority or authenticity to Christians.

You would instead need to try to make your case from the Bible. It's a hard case to make since the Bible pretty clearly indicates he is God, though it is always by implication rather than directly claiming "I am God." Rather it says Jesus made statements that, to the people at the time, would imply a claim of Godship. (And in several cases resulted in them trying to kill him for blasphemy. ) At that point it mostly degrades to trying to prove those claims miss attributed.

You are also unlikely to make much progress in convincing him as well.  This debate has been going on for centuries with both sides thinking their view is abundantly supported and obvious.

The benefit of interfaith dialog is much more on making sure we understand each others views.  Fundamentally you aren't going to convince someone logically one way or the other. You can counter some objections that result from misunderstandings and ensure your views are well and clearly understood, but that isn't going to convince someone to change their beliefs unless a misconception of your beliefs was their main barrier.

(Full disclaimer, I am a Christian answering this from a Christians perspective in the interest of encouraging interfaith dialog. )

Comment: I have never come across a Chrisitan that could even show that Jesus even hinted towards Godship.

Answer (score 2):

To explain Jesus's divinity or lack thereof to a Christian, you could start by referring to materials produced by Christians for Christians.

Jehovah's Witnesses are a Christian denomination with a non-trinitarian interpretation of the Bible, which some other denominations call unorthodox.
One of these beliefs is that Jesus is not God but instead the son of God born through Maryam as a surrogate mother.
Try looking over what Witnesses believe about Jesus and the reasoning they use.
Start with [Is Jesus Almighty God?](http://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/is-jesus-almighty/) and follow the links.
You'll find that, for example, the Bible calls Jesus "mighty" but calls only God "almighty".

Watch Tower Bible and Tract Society, the publisher operated by the denomination, has published a book called *The Time for True Submission to God*.
It starts by stating what Witnesses and Muslims agree on and then introducing what they disagree on.
It is written from a view of proselytizing a Muslim to become a Witness, so be careful in how you approach it, but you might be able to find some good ideas with scriptural backing, and it'll help you understand Christian views in at least a broad sense.
See if you can find a Witness and hit him or her up for a copy of this book, as well as *What Does the Bible Really Teach?* which touches on the difference between Witness doctrine and orthodox Christianity.

Another thing to watch out for when using Watch Tower literature is that some Christians really don't like Jehovah's Witnesses, believing them to be a dangerous cult.
So don't mention Jehovah's Witnesses or directly quote their literature.
Instead stick to the cited scripture and put the reasoning in your own words.

Answer (score 1):

Following with the idea above, for a christian they will need to see some evidence in their own faith to prove otherwise, much like you would not accept statements from a religious text outside the Qur'an on the status of figures in the Qur'an.  So sadly you are not going to find what you need in the Qur'an, however there are multiple instances to use Christianity to prove your point to some extent.

If you want to make Jesus of Nazarene a mortal, look to the early council of Nicaea where he was made divine.

As with all religious text, interpretation is key.  Much of the initial theology of Christianity was solidified in the council of Nicaea that created the three face god of father son holy spirit that can be regarded as one entity in three forms.  However there are other interpretations.  And in fact as you look to translations and interpretations you can infer that Jesus viewed himself as a child of god as all people are children of god.   And although he had a personal relationship with his God, he never claimed a exclusive status as part of god or divine depending on how you read the text.  This was  a latter addition to the theology in order too unite the faiths.  But arguably Jesus did not fit well into a divine monarchy.  Most of his teachings were about equality of all people himself included. So the council of Nicaea made him a perfect being by making him part of god. Once again this is a matter of interpretation of translations.

cases in point

Jesus as The Son of God .  The new testament was written mostly in Greek and the Greek language does not have an equivalent definitive article to the word '**The**'.  at no point does this sentence ever happen in the original text, Jesus THE son of God.  This was added in later by translators in order to make the text more readable in a new language.  instead an alternative translation might be Jesus **a** son of God . . . . makes him as mortal as us all.

as i am clarifying this is an interpretation.  I will ask anybody to find Greek writing with the word 'the' present in it. The is an English word, that we have attached to a Greek word to make sense of the Greek language. However there are plenty of reasons to translate the word as 'a' on 'in'.  You might also be surprised that 'she' is missing from Greek as well.  They do have  definitive articles but the equivalent articles are translations.  We attach our words in a fashion to another languages words to make sense of the language but these interpretation are open to different meanings and have often been revised.  If you think translation is a simple 1-1 equivalency you might be surprised.  There is a link below about Greek language.

John 14:6 New International Version (NIV)

6 Jesus answered, “I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me."

This is heavily translated and interpreted, This is commonly accepted to mean that you must accept Jesus as a personal savoir who will intercede on your behalf to god.  Once again this time the 'through me' is a interpretation, it can also me read to mean through my teachings .  This moves Jesus away from being a divine being providing intercession to a great teacher providing guidance.

So most of this hinges on the early formation of the churches and how people interpreted their religions.  Keeping in mind what we call Christianity was formed in the earl 300's CE at the council of Nicaea.

And once again, my interpretations. And interpretations that have been handed down and reemphasized.  There are numerous Christian traditions going wherever form the Greek orthodox to the Coptic Christians to David kuresh.   Knowing your friends tradition will aid your discourse.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea

http://www.skeptically.org/newtestament/id8.html

http://www.foundalis.com/lan/definart.htm

Good luck and have fun philosophizing on religiosity!

Comment: "...the Greek language does not have an equivalent definitive article to the word 'The'". Are you quite sure about that? ;-)

Comment: -1 for multiple factual mistakes for with regards to both Greek language and the Biblical text. Here is your example of Jesus being called "THE SON OF GOD" in Greek in Mark 3:11. "καὶ τὰ πνεύματα τὰ ἀκάθαρτα, ὅταν αὐτὸν ἐθεώρουν, προσέπιπτον αὐτῷ καὶ ἔκραζον λέγοντα ὅτι Σὺ εἶ **ὁ Υἱὸς τοῦ Θεοῦ**." **ὁ  is the Greek for "the"** (for masculine singular nouns). Yios = son, tou = of, and Theou = God. [Here](http://www.ntgreek.net/lesson13.htm#article) is a chart giving all the ways the definite article "the" is found in Greek texts depending on gender, plurality, and case.

Answer (score 0):

Christians are taught that Jesus was the prophesied Messiah.   The Book of Daniel (Ch 2) tells of Daniel interpreting a dream of four kingdoms, the fourth of which is the Roman Empire.  During that period God will set up a new (heavenly) kingdom that will stand forever.  The Book of Daniel (Ch 9) also tells of a Messiah who will arrive and bring a new, holy kingdom.  Christ arrived during the Roman occupation of the Holy City and said he would establish his kingdom.

Christians believe the only way to get to heaven is to be in that kingdom.

There are many instances of the apostles pleading that the gospel story remain forever unchanged.  Throughout the New Testament there are warnings against listening to false teachers. In his letter to the Galatians (Ch 1) Paul warned that even if an angel from heaven were to preach a new and different gospel he should be cursed!

When the angel Gabriel appeared to Mohammad (May He Rest In Peace), he did just that – he claimed he was from heaven and offered a new and attractive story.  Consequently the chances a knowledgeable Christian will convert to Islam is remote.

On the other hand, the people who claim to be Christian but do not know the basics of their own religion are legion!  And are ripe for conversion to Islam.

Answer (score 0):

Muslims pray to the Father only and believe that jesus is a prophet

these two sections of the quran describes who is jesus in islam https://quran.com/19/16-40 https://quran.com/3/45-100

jesus is supported by the holy spirit according to quran

> quran 2:87 And We did certainly give Moses the Torah and followed up
>   after him with messengers. And We gave Jesus, the son of Mary, clear
>   proofs and supported him with the Pure Spirit. But is it [not] that
>   every time a messenger came to you, [O Children of Israel], with what
>   your souls did not desire, you were arrogant? And a party [of
>   messengers] you denied and another party you killed

jesus denying calling himself a god in judgement day

> quran 5:110 [The Day] when Allah will say, "O Jesus, Son of Mary,
>   remember My favor upon you and upon your mother when I supported you
>   with the Pure Spirit and you spoke to the people in the cradle and in
>   maturity; and [remember] when I taught you writing and wisdom and the
>   Torah and the Gospel; and when you designed from clay [what was] like
>   the form of a bird with My permission, then you breathed into it, and
>   it became a bird with My permission; and you healed the blind and the
>   leper with My permission; and when you brought forth the dead with My
>   permission; and when I restrained the Children of Israel from
>   [killing] you when you came to them with clear proofs and those who
>   disbelieved among them said, "This is not but obvious magic."
>
> quran 5:116 : And [beware the Day] when Allah will say, "O Jesus, Son
>   of Mary, did you say to the people, 'Take me and my mother as deities
>   besides Allah ?'" He will say, "Exalted are You! It was not for me to
>   say that to which I have no right. If I had said it, You would have
>   known it. You know what is within myself, and I do not know what is
>   within Yourself. Indeed, it is You who is Knower of the unseen.

quran(God's word) refuses the idea of trinity :

> quran 5:3-75 They have certainly disbelieved who say, " Allah is the
>   third of three." And there is no god except one God. And if they do
>   not desist from what they are saying, there will surely afflict the
>   disbelievers among them a painful punishment.So will they not repent
>   to Allah and seek His forgiveness? And Allah is Forgiving and
>   Merciful. The Messiah, son of Mary, was not but a messenger; [other]
>   messengers have passed on before him. And his mother was a supporter
>   of truth. They both used to eat food. Look how We make clear to them
>   the signs; then look how they are deluded.

the angel is a spirit (bible)

> Zechariah 6:4 So I inquired of the angel who was speaking with me,
>   “What are these, my lord?” 5.And the angel told me, “These are the
>   four spirits of heaven, going out from their station before the Lord
>   of all the earth

Matthew 7:21-23

> “Not everyone who says to Me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ shall enter the kingdom of
>   heaven, but he who does the will of My Father in heaven. 22 Many will
>   say to Me in that day, ‘Lord, Lord, have we not prophesied in Your
>   name, cast out demons in Your name, and done many wonders in Your
>   name?’ 23 And then I will declare to them, ‘I never knew you; depart
>   from Me, you who practice lawlessness!’

Matthew 24:36

> "No one knows about that day or hour, not even the angels in heaven,
>   nor the Son, but only the Father. "

John 17:3

> Now this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only TRUE God,
>   and Jesus Christ, whom You have sent.

John 20:17

> Jesus said, “Do not hold on to me, for I have not yet ascended to the
>   Father. Go instead to my brothers and tell them, ‘I am ascending to my
>   Father and your Father, to my God and your God.’”

Answer (score -1):

Coming from a country who has a majority of Muslim, i don't see there is any way you can convince a christian that Jesus is not the Son of GOD. Yes Jesus was the son of Maryam in a way, after-all she did conceived Jesus (but not through physical contact like you and me). Maryam was pregnant through the power of the Holy Spirit.  Maryam was GOD vessel, GOD can use anyone but HE chose to bless Maryam. Unless your Christian friend foundation is not strong, there's no way you can convince him.

Answer (score -1):

In the bible all prophet were called son of God.Eg:(Exodus 4:22,Jermiah 3:19)The king of Israel like David are God's sons so it means he was not begotten son of God as all the prophet were called son of God in the Bible.U will see that Jesus(pbuh) used to bathe,urinate,drink,ate,sleep etc... so how can God do manly things is it possible!

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** Just based on Qur'an **convincing** them is difficult, because they don't believe, but just remind them about the truth if they [fear the Father](http://quran.com/50/45).

I guess this answer is still open because the question asks the verses from Qur'an as a help in an attempt to prove that Jesus(pbuh) is not God, rather than focusing on how to prove Jesus(pbuh) is not God simply. As described above, I won't discourage you that Christians are not going to believe you no matter how many verses from Qur'an you show it is of no use, I encourage you by trying to help you accumulate verses from the Qur'an to show them. And most importantly, your job is to just remind them of the truth that's it. You won't be asked why did you fail to convince them, if they had to become Muslims, surely God would have guided them all. So, let not their refusal stop you from warning.

---

Firstly, shaitan promised he would misguide people and take them along with him to hell.

There is no God but one God the Father, who created everything including Jesus (pbuh).

> And your god is one God. There is no deity [worthy of worship] except Him, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful. (Qur'an 2:163)

He is not God, as he is relying on his father for everything.

Next, Jesus(pbuh) said

> Indeed, Allah is my Lord and your Lord, so worship Him. That is the straight path." (Qur'an 3:51)

The same thing is there even in [Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2022%3A34-39&version=NIV) emphasizing the worship of Lord God.

Again the same thing is repeated in Qur'an

> They have certainly disbelieved who say, "**Allah is the Messiah**, the son of Mary" while the Messiah has said, "O Children of Israel, worship Allah , my Lord and your Lord." Indeed, he who associates others with Allah - Allah has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire. And there are not for the wrongdoers any helpers. (Qur'an 5:72)

This time more clear to those who say, Jesus is God, or God is Jesus.

This further helps us understand that Jesus did not have divinely nature.

> The Messiah, son of Mary, was not but a messenger; [other] messengers have passed on before him. And his mother was a supporter of truth. **They both used to eat food. Look how We make clear to them the signs; then look how they are deluded.** (Qur'an 5:75)
>
> Say (O Muhammad SAW to mankind): "How do you worship besides Allah something which has no power either to harm or to benefit you? But it is Allah Who is the All-Hearer, All-Knower." (Qur'an 5:76)

Everywhere in the Bible, Jesus(pbuh) focused on the word "The Father", emphasizing Allah, rather if he were to be God, then he would've commanded his disciples simply saying, "worship me that's fine. I'll grant you heaven". No, he said, he is the ticket to heaven, to ultimately reach the father, you need to hold fast to me, meaning perfectly follow me to reach the Father. Because Father doesn't like the wrong doing people, Jesus(pbuh) came to guide the lost sheep of Israel, to take them back to the father through him. You can find a near summary of his teachings in [Mathew 10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2010&version=NIV), but again there he emphasized on **doing righteous deeds by loving him**.

> Say (O Muhammad SAW): "O people of the Scripture (Jews and Christians)! Exceed not the limits in your religion (by believing in something) other than the truth, and do not follow the vain desires of people who went astray in times gone by, and who misled many, and strayed (themselves) from the Right Path." (Qur'an 5:77)

This clearly warns the Christians don't try to over understand the Bible, but just understand what is clear and precise. Rather don't exceed your limits, don't follow the vain desires of the people who misled many. These words can be clearly attributed to the disciples of Jesus (pbuh) who invented all extra concepts of Jesus(pbuh) being God. In short, I can tell you to advice him to at least follow the Unitarian Christians, who don't say Jesus(pbuh) is God.

**No where in the Bible did Jesus(pbuh) implicitly say that 'I'm God'. It is they perceive things which are not clear, there by leading themselves to Fitna.**

But the way people perceive things changed over time. At the very beginning, his disciples clearly understood him as the only son of God, later, if he could be son of God, then he is also God. Based on "I and the father are one" as said by Jesus(pbuh) they claim he is god but you need to prove them that this statement doesn't mean Jesus(pbuh) is god, but means 'what ever I say/do, it's because the father has inspired in me'. But the shaitan is sure to deceive people in what ever way possible. He leads them to follow the footsteps of their ancestors and fulfills his promise of taking people to hell. He could ask, Why is that, just believing Jesus (pbuh) is God, so wrong? Then I ask 'why is that just not believing Jesus (pbuh) is God not right? I mean, all you need to do, you can still be a perfect Christian by following him perfectly along with being a near believer just by not believing Jesus (pbuh) is God'.

**If they read things clearly from the Bible (Old Testament), any common person with basic understanding could doubt [is it not wrong to call Jesus (pbuh) as God](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25112/is-it-wrong-to-say-jesus-is-the-god-of-the-old-testament) based on Old Testament, but unfortunately the reminder of the people delude him.**

**They are still trying their level best to prove Jesus (pbuh) is God, but all they can do is convince people but can't prove.**

---

**Friendly reminder**, 2day, most Christians are deluded by the false notions created by the inferences made by the disciples. Although the disciples never themselves talked about the concept Trinity implicitly, later generations created it. So, if you really care for your friend that he/she should not enter Hell, then you need to prove to him/her 2 more things, i.e. Trinity is wrong (Qur'an [5:73](http://quran.com/5/73)), & Jesus (pbuh) being literal or 'only' son is wrong (Qur'an [39:4](http://quran.com/39/4) & Qur'an [21:26](http://quran.com/21/26)). If you can't prove them these 3 things are wrong, then

> **O you who believe! Take not the Jews and the Christians as Auliya' (friends, protectors, helpers, etc.), they are but Auliya' to one another. And if any amongst you takes them as Auliya', then surely he is one of them. Verily, Allah guides not those people who are the Zalimun (polytheists and wrong-doers and unjust).** (Qur'an 5:51)

Please don't waste your precious time.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score -3):

Jesus himself says something along the lines of "Who do you say I am" to the apostles... He says he himself is the king of the Jews - this was the accusation by the Romans. And I believe he did not actually ever describe himself as anything else.

I dispute that Christians would not respect the Muslim texts - I think they would be seen them as writings of a holy man.  And certainly both religions believe in one and the same god and respect each others religions and have worked well alongside one another in most cases. Witness the funeral of John Paul 11 etc.

If people believe in a real God really the last thing they would be having is silly arguments - we would be in awe of this great creator and trying our best to make the world a  better place full of love.

Answer (score -4):

### This is how you can prove it to him using the Bible.

Jesus is indeed is the son of Mariam and the messenger for "The All". A prophet without sin.

> Jesus said to her, “I who speak to you am He.” (John 4:26 NKJV)

To one that does not understand his ministry this sounds as a statement that Jesus is saying "I am He." "I" meaning "the Man Speaking". However this is not the case. "I" is specified as "who speak to you". So it is the "Words am He".

**God is One he is the Word**

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. (John 1:1 NKJV)

**The Misunderstanding**

> But Jesus kept silent. And the high priest answered and said to Him, “I put You under oath by the living God: Tell us if You are the Christ, the Son of God!”
>
> 64 Jesus said to him, “It is as you said. Nevertheless, I say to you, hereafter you will see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of the Power, and coming on the clouds of heaven.”(Matthew 26:63-64 NKJV)

This term "Son of Man" does not apply to the Prophet. It applies to what is birthed from man. The words birthed from man. Here Jesus corrects the high priest "It is as you said." Here God is speaking to Jesus through the High Priest, and Jesus Agrees.

> Nevertheless, I say to you, hereafter you will see the Words birthed from Man sitting at the right hand of the Power, and coming on the clouds of heaven. (DeCoded)

**The Reason it was said to the Priest like this**

> “I was watching in the night visions, And behold, One like the Son of Man, Coming with the clouds of heaven! He came to the Ancient of Days, And they brought Him near before Him. 14 Then to Him was given dominion and glory and a kingdom, That all peoples, nations, and languages should serve Him. His dominion is an everlasting dominion, Which shall not pass away, And His kingdom the one Which shall not be destroyed. (Daniel 7:13-14 NKJV)

**The Biblical Proof**

> He answered and said to them: “He who sows the good seed is the Son of Man." (Matthew 13:37 NKJV)
>
> And He said, “The kingdom of God is as if a man should scatter seed on the ground (Mark 4:26)
>
> Now the parable is this: The seed is the word of God. (Luke 8:11)

- The Sower = Any man who should speak.
- The Seed = The Words of God.

**God is One: Explained by the Prophet**

> Jesus answered him, “The first of all the commandments is: ‘Hear, O Israel, the Lord our God, the Lord is one. 30 And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart, with all your soul, with all your mind, and with all your strength.’ This is the first commandment. (Mark 12:29-30 NKJV)

**Scientific Proof**
"The All" is made of Matter. Matter is made of Atoms. Atoms are made of Particles. Particles are made of Waves. These Waves are made of Vibrations. These Vibrations Come from God. All Vibration is God.

The Words we speak are Vibration. The words we speak are God.

**Even More Proof**

> Then Pilate asked Him, “Are You the King of the Jews?”
>
> He answered and said to him, “It is as you say.” (Mark 15:2 NKJV)

**The Power of the Spoken Word**

> “Lord, do not trouble Yourself, for I am not worthy that You should enter under my roof. 7 Therefore I did not even think myself worthy to come to You. But **say the word**, and my servant will be healed. 8 For I also am a man placed under authority, having soldiers under me. And I say to one, ‘Go,’ and he goes; and to another, ‘Come,’ and he comes; and to my servant, ‘Do this,’ and he does it.”
>
> 9 When Jesus heard these things, He marveled at him, and turned around and said to the crowd that followed Him, “I say to you, I have not found such great faith, not even in Israel!”  (Luke 7:6b-9 NKJV)

**Conclusion**
The Father is what is thought. The Son is what is spoken. Everything Else is "The All". The One True God.

Answer (score -7):

The truth is that Isa is the son of god through the religion of israel from the old testament. He knows the truth from the kingdom of god(allah), all followers of Allah are the son of Allah, adam, abram, jacob, and issac etc.
This prophet isa received evil spirit and started to claim to be god.

Comment: He claimed what gets said was from God. Similar to your prophet Muhammad he said a thing, and it was from God. And the words of Allah do come from Allah, therefore since his spirit(breath) was Allah and his words from Allah, his spirit is perfect as Allah is perfect! Isa claims Allah as God and there is nothing evil about that. Therefore woe to those that do not recognize the words of Allah, casting them aside. And woe to those that claim the words of Allah evil. And woe to those rejecting the words of Allah out of confusion thinking Christians claim three, Allah is, speaks, and breaths.

Comment: In Jewish thinking a son gets born from someone. In your Quran who was Isa's father? It was Allah's words "Be" even as stated in your Quran. A word is a word, and a word from Allah is a word from Allah. And if that word from Allah became flesh, it was Allah's doing. And if man needs to classify a person as someones son, that's simply a perspective, and a perspective is a perspective. Obviously Allah understands the correct perspective. And when Allah tries to teach using this same perspective to man, calling the words that man says as the "Son of Man", it shows Allah's understanding.

Comment: And if Allah understands enough to use this perspective in his teachings, then you should open up your understanding to really understand what Allah said. Yet whether you reject this or confirm to understanding, it shows Allah's understanding and mercy, therefore blessings go to Allah, regardless what this blasphemer says or thinks.